# Is Adobe Flex all XML-based?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

I am trying to develop an Android application and I heard that for someone with less-than-superior java skills, AIR/Flex might be a good place to start.

I am noticing that all I see in Flash Builder is MXML-based. Is this how all of the code in Flex written? Via XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "XML". MXML can contain chunks of ActionScript code both in blocks between `<script>` tags and right in line in attributes to controls tags, such as

```
<s:button click="someObject.DoSomething()">
```

This ActionScript embedded in MXML file is the pattern largely presented in the Flex in a Week series noted by @www-flextras-com.

But you can also have full, dedicated ActionScript files, both directly associated with .mxml objects and all by themselves. This "Code-Behind" design pattern is very much like the XAML design + C# code-behind combination in Windows Presentation Foundation applications.

An good introduction with a viewable example of strict code-behind in Flex :

- [Article](http://blogs.adobe.com/paulw/archives/2007/11/presentation_pa_5.html)
- [Browseable source code](http://examples.pmwilliams.co.uk/adobeblog/presentationpatterns/codebehind/srcview/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Flex is a declarative, tag-based way of writing rich applications.  Under the hood it is all ActionScript, though, so it is very easy to marry ActionScript code into a Flex application (as you often must do).

When I have coded with Flex, I use it as a declarative language.  I use the tags to build out Views and data-driven containers.  Then I write ActionScript classes to do all the imperative control logic.  The relationship is similar to the one between JSP and Java, or (sort of) HTML and JavaScript.

In a nutshell though, yes, you can write whole Flex applications with its XML-like syntax and resort to ActionScript just to glue bits and pieces together, write small handler functions, etc.

This guy is a Flex genius and wrote a great book on it: http://dougmccune.com/blog/

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Flex is a mix of MXML and ActionScript.  MXML is indeed XML based; but ActionScript is an ECMA compliant language.  Conceptually similar to JavaScript.

I suggest you start by reading through the [Flex docs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/documentation.html) to give you some background.  The [Flex in a Week tutorials](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html) come strongly recommended.